Counting items in an array and making counts into columns
I am working in databricks where I have a dataframe as follows:
dummy_df
names  items

Ash    [c1,c2,c2,c3]
Bob    [c1,c2]
May    []
Amy    [c2,c3,c3]

Where names column contains strings for values and items is a column of arrays.
I would like to count how many times each item appears for each name and make each count into a column. So the desired output will look something like so:
names  items           c1_count c2_count c3_count

Ash    [c1,c2,c2,c3]   1        2        1
Bob    [c1,c2]         1        1        0
May    []              0        0        0
Amy    [c2,c3,c3]      0        1        2

So far my approach is to count each item separately using aggregate as so:
c1_count = dummy_df.select("*", explode("items").alias("exploded"))\
    .where(col("exploded").isin(['c1']))\
    .groupBy("names", "items")\
    .agg(count("exploded").alias("c1_count"))
c2_count = ...
c3_count = ...

And then I concatenate a new df by taking count columns from my new 3 dataframes and adding them to my dummy_df. But that is very inefficient and if I were to have many items in my arrays (say 50-100), it may even be impractical.
I wonder if there is a better way? Can I somehow calculate the count of all items and make such counts into the columns without needing to count them individually and do massive concatenation as the end?

Leaving a comment to mention that all suggestions are working and are acceptable solutions.

Explode the column items and then use crosstab to get the number of items for each name.
exploded_df = dummy_df.explode('items')

crosstab_df = (pd.crosstab(exploded_df['names'], exploded_df['items'], dropna=False)
               .drop(columns=np.nan)
               .add_prefix('Count_')
               .reset_index()
              )
new_df = df.merge(crosstab_df, on='names')

Output:
  names             items  Count_c1  Count_c2  Count_c3
0   Ash  [c1, c2, c2, c3]         1         2         1
1   Bob          [c1, c2]         1         1         0
2   May                []         0         0         0
3   Amy      [c2, c3, c3]         0         1         2

This is the data I used:
data = {'names': ['Ash', 'Bob', 'May', 'Amy'], 
        'items': [['c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3'], ['c1', 'c2'], [], ['c2', 'c3', 'c3']]}

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Example Code
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'names': ['Ash', 'Bob', 'May', 'Amy'],
    'items': [['c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3'], ['c1', 'c2'], [], ['c2', 'c3', 'c3']]
}

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dummy_df
 names             items
0   Ash  [c1, c2, c2, c3]
1   Bob          [c1, c2]
2   May                []
3   Amy      [c2, c3, c3]

Code
out = dummy_df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(dummy_df['items'].explode())
      .groupby(level=0).sum()
      .add_suffix('_count')
)

out
  names             items  c1_count  c2_count  c3_count
0   Ash  [c1, c2, c2, c3]         1         2         1
1   Bob          [c1, c2]         1         1         0
2   May                []         0         0         0
3   Amy      [c2, c3, c3]         0         1         2


You could map collections.Counter then build a DataFrame:
from collections import Counter

out = dummy_df.join(pd.DataFrame(map(Counter, dummy_df['items'])))

To have 0s:
out = dummy_df.join(pd.DataFrame(map(Counter, dummy_df['items']))
                      .fillna(0).convert_dtypes())

Output:
  names             items  c1  c2  c3
0   Ash  [c1, c2, c2, c3]   1   2   1
1   Bob          [c1, c2]   1   1   0
2   May                []   0   0   0
3   Amy      [c2, c3, c3]   0   1   2


Explode the items array, pivot the DataFrame and count the occurrences of each item and join the original DataFrame with the result DataFrame:
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

exploded_df = dummy_df.select("names",explode(col("items")).alias("item"))
result_df = exploded_df.groupBy("names").pivot("item").count().na.fill(0)
final_df = dummy_df.join(result_df, on="names")


Surprised nobody recommended using get_dummies yet.
I use explode to explode the items series, then groupby the index and sum up the True (1) and False (0) values.
I end it with using pd.concat to merge the DataFrames:
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['items'].explode()).add_suffix('_count')
dummies = pd.concat([df, dummies.groupby(dummies.index).sum()], axis=1)
print(dummies)

Output:
  names             items  c1_count  c2_count  c3_count
0   Ash  [c1, c2, c2, c3]         1         2         1
1   Bob          [c1, c2]         1         1         0
2   May                []         0         0         0
3   Amy      [c2, c3, c3]         0         1         2

